# Android Studio Canary 4.2 is rebuilding my project automatically every time I make a change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

It might be a dumb question or maybe an issue on my side: since I downloaded Android Studio 4.2 Preview (Canary) to try Jetpack Compose, every time I change a few words in my activity, the project just rebuilds by itself. It's super annoying because when I write a single word, it tries to compile and end up with an error (since I couldn't even finish writing the code line) with the cursor going to the beginning of the line...

Is this feature intended? And how can I disable it?

Comment: I feel the same! Auto-Preview tries to render on every single keystroke and it doesn't really show the result until it ends up with error to make us click on Build & Refresh button manually. So what's the point? Need a way to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-build is a feature on Canary, I do experience the weird keyboard movement to the error. I think the Build on Save might fix this but not quite sure. Just find it on top of the design tab[image: designtab]